# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied, certificates issue in IIS7

Tags: ssl, client, certificate

I have installed a renewed SSL certificate on my web server running IIS7.

After installation, I applied website binding to port 443.

My application uses client certificates too, so I have changed the SSL setting to Require 'client certificate'.

Both client and SSL server certificates are valid but still I am not able to access my application. The error I get is:

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

I have enabled client certificate mapping in IIS role settings also but still not getting rid of this 403 error.

I guess client certificate is not able to handshake with server certificate. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

In certificate Store verified all server certificate and client cert with its authority hierarchy are available.

also cross check below settings

Application Authentication: Anonymous
Application SSL Setting: Require SSL/ Accept
ApplicationHost.config: enabled OnetoOneMapping under iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication also added base64 certificate mapped with service accounts

Also based on my past experience we need to ensure we have SChannel registry setting as mentioned in below post. 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2464556

Answer (score -2):

Simplest workaround just discovered this today. In IIS for your application, Go to Edit Bindings and change your port number. 443 to 4431 or 44301. Any variation you want. In your client computer, type in the new URL using new port number and you will establish a fresh connection to application. Make sure you SSL Settings for IIS Application is set to "Accept" instead of "Require". This means you can click "Cancel" when the pop up asks you to select a certificate you can simply hit "Cancel" and still hit the site. No 403 Error.

Do not spend hours trying to mess with your certificate store, just simply change the port on IIS Server and you'll be fine.

Comment: But that's not the requirement.